# c# SOAP VAT get validate

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, soap, soap-client

In my project i add the reference http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl and in my code I do:

```
   ServiceReferenceVAT.checkVatRequest check = new ServiceReferenceVAT.checkVatRequest();
       check.Body.vatNumber = "IT";
       check.Body.countryCode = "01983251678";
```

Now, I don't know how call a method to vaildate. This method doesn't appear when I do check. (...), How I validate my vat code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this link as the anwswer to the question: https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2016/03/15/using-the-official-vies-api-in-c-for-vat-lookups/

```
var vat = new ServiceReferenceVAT.checkVatPortTypeClient();
           bool blnValid;
           string strName;
           string strAddress;
           string strCountryCode = "PT";
           string strVatNumber = "509358772";
       var t = vat.checkVat(ref strCountryCode, ref strVatNumber, out blnValid, out strName, out strAddress);
```

Comment: Obrigado Judas xD